# How to pass a value to a parameter in a script

Tags: javascript

I want to change the value of data-amount dynamically. When i enter a amount in a text box that amount should be assign to the parameter 'data-amount'

My script:

```
<script async="async" src="js/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=email@hmail.com"
                    data-button="button"  data-quantity="1" data-amount="50.00"
                  data-shipping="0" data-tax="0">
                </script>
```

Comment: use `$('.paypal-button').find('[name="amount"]').val(your_price)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -
Change `'inputText` according to your text field class.

```
$(".inputText").blur(function(){
    $("html").find("script").attr("data-amount",$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the following js and html snippet where the button value changes on change of value in text box

```
<html>

<script> 

 function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("btn").value=document.getElementById('txt').value;
 }
</script>
 <input type="button" value="" id='btn'/>
 <input type="text" id='txt' onkeydown="myFunction()">

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only change the value of `name="amount"` in the form generated by the script.

When you put the script

```
<script async="async" src="js/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=email@hmail.com"
                    data-button="button"  data-quantity="1" data-amount="50.00"
                  data-shipping="0" data-tax="0">
                </script>
```

It create a form in the page like this

```
    <form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal-button" target="_top">
  <div class="hide" id="errorBox"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="button" value="button">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@hmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_button">
  <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www">
  <button type="submit" class="paypal-button large">undefined</button>
</form>
```

And when you enter a amount in a text box, change the form value only

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pay_amount').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.paypal-button').find('[name="amount"]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=email@hmail.com" data-button="button" data-quantity="1" data-amount="50.00" data-shipping="0" data-tax="0">
</script>

<input type="text" id="pay_amount" />
```